# what is api-paste.ini file in openstack

Tags: openstack, python-paste

I've seen api-paste.ini as a conf file after installing openstack.
It looks like substituting some prefixes for python implementation but have no clue about this.
Here, my questions are:

What script is it? 
it looks like very bizarre grammar like the following:

```
[composite:metadata]
use = egg:Paste#urlmap
/: meta
```

How does it work within python script?

Answer (score 11):

See documentation for [Paste Deploy](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy).

The `api-paste.ini` is the configuration for the above web-services framework. Paste.deploy allows you to separate concerns between writing your application and middleware/filters from the composition of them into a web service. You define you WSGI applications and any middleware filters in the configuration file then you can compose pipelines which include the middleware/filters you want into your web-service, e.g. authentication, rate-limiting, etc. 
You want to temporarily remove authentication, take it out of your pipeline and restart your web service.
The declaration above is declaring a composite application, but with only one application binding (a bit unnecessary - normally you would expect to see more than one binding, e.g. for different versions of the application). The WSGI application `app:meta` will be bound to `/` and you should have a declaration of `app:meta` later in the file. The implementation of the composite app is declared via the `use` and the `egg:Paste#urlmap` is a simple reference implementation. 
You load this in your program with `paste.deploy.loadwsgi.loadapp()`.
There is a proposal/recommendation(?) to move away from Paste Deploy/WebOb to WSME/Pecan see [OpenStack Common WSGI](https://etherpad.openstack.org/havana-common-wsgi)